# Is it possible to recognise a person based on what they have written?

Tags: natural-language-processing, reference-request, computational-linguistics

I needed to make a system for recognizing people based on hundreds of texts by finding similarities in their written text grammatically or similarities between words they choose for writing. I don't want it so accurate, but I wanted to know if it is possible.

For example, finding one person with two accounts or more on a forum or something in that case (texts already gathered). I'm just wondering if it's possible and what field should I research for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you are looking for is [stylometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylometry), which is related to a technique in forensic linguistics called [writeprint analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writeprint). There are many different techniques to perform stylometric analysis, from the very basic 5-feature analysis classifying features such as the lexicon and idiosyncrasies unique to a person to more complex analysis utilizing neural networks and machine learning. Searching online for research papers focusing on stylometry should assist you in finding the best technique for the job.